# How many combinations can you make from ABCDD

Tags: math

If you are given 5 letters and 2 of them are the same e.g. ABCDD. How can you find out quickly how many different combinations they can be arranged into?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of combinations are actually n!

But in your specific case when there are exactly 2 characters that are the same (no more, no less) and at least 3 characters, not only "DD") the answer is:

n!/2

n! implies the factorial function.

Factorial(2) = 2
2 * 1

Factorial(3) = 6
3 * 2 * 1

Factorial(4) = 24
4 * 3 * 2 * 1

So in your example "ABCDD", the length (n) is 5 (length of string).
So 5!/2 is the answer.

Factorial(5) = 120, 120/2 = 60

There are 120 different combinations of the string "ABCDD" but if you only want the uniqie ones the answer is 60.

As i mentioned above this only work if you have 2 characters that are the same (no more and no less) and a length of at least 3 characters / at least 2 unique characters.